# fitSharp.Machine.Exception.TypeMissingException: Type 'a1' not found in assemblies

Tags: .net, fitnesse

Trying to reproduce a simple FitNesse example, run into this "TypeMissingException" problem.

Tried to specify full paths, makes no difference. The paths appear to work fine. The class in the fixture is recognised (`FitnessTest.Multiply`); but the variable on the class, `public int a1;` is not recognised but generates the exception as in the title.

Test page:

```
    !define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer,fitsharp\bin\fit.dll %p}
    !define TEST_RUNNER {fitsharp\bin\Runner.exe}
    !path test\bin\FitnesseTest.dll

    !| FitnesseTest.Multiply |
    | a1 | a2 | Times? |
    | 10 | 2 | 20 |
    | 12 | 3 | 36 |
    | 100 | 4 | 33 |
```

Fixture:

```
    namespace FitnesseTest
    {
        public class Multiply : fit.ColumnFixture
        {
            public int a1;
            public int a2;

            public int Times()
            {
                return a1 * a2;
            }
        }
    }
```

The result:

```
    Test Pages: 0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions     Assertions: 0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 1 exceptions (0.609 seconds)

    variable defined: COMMAND_PATTERN=%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer,fitsharp\bin\fit.dll %p 
    variable defined: TEST_RUNNER=fitsharp\bin\Runner.exe 
    classpath: test\bin\FitnesseTest.dll

    FitnesseTest.Multiply
    a1
    fitSharp.Machine.Exception.TypeMissingException: Type 'a1' not found in assemblies:
        file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
        file:///E:/dev/FitNesse/fitsharp/bin/Runner.exe
        file:///E:/dev/FitNesse/fitsharp/bin/fitSharp.DLL
        file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
        file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
        file:///E:/dev/FitNesse/fitsharp/bin/fit.DLL
        file:///E:/dev/FitNesse/test/bin/FitnesseTest.dll

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an extra blank line in your test?  When I run your test as posted here, it works fine.  If I put a extra blank line after the fixture name, I can reproduce your problem:

```
!| FitnesseTest.Multiply |

| a1 | a2 | Times? |
| 10 | 2 | 20 |
| 12 | 3 | 36 |
| 100 | 4 | 33 |
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I don't have a blank line; but I think I have clued in to the problem, at least to some extent: it's version conflicts. The problem as described was observed when I used fitsharp that I built myself from the solution (target: 4.5.2). The fixture was built, I think (don't have my machine in front of me now), for core2.2. Since then I found your answer to another question, which led me to getting fitsharp from nuget (target: 4.7.1, if memory serves). Also tried to target the fixture for standard2.0. Now the problem has morphed to "File system.runtime 4.2.0.0 is missing". Argh.